# how do you run a php script from other directories

Tags: php

I have this php script that utilizes ssh. I have my php installed on c:\php directory. When I run this script right from this directory it works. But If I try to run this script from other directories by using absolute path, it is giving me all kinds of errors:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot>c:\php\php c:\php\get_cpu1.php
PHP Warning:  require_once(Math/BigInteger.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\PHP\Net\SSH2.php on line 746

Warning: require_once(Math/BigInteger.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\PHP\Net\SSH2.php on line 746
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Math/BigInteger.php' (include_path='C:/PHP/pear') in C:\PHP\Net\SSH2.php on line 746

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Math/BigInteger.php' (include_path='C:/PHP/pear') in C:\PHP\Net\SSH2.php on line 746
```

Any ideas what I am missing here?

This is the code to get_cpu1.php

```
<?php

include('C:/PHP/Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('server1.example.com');
if (!$ssh->login('user', 'passwd')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

//echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
$line= $ssh->exec('tail -1 /var/log/messages');
//echo $line;
unset($ssh);
?>
```

Comment: Please post the code of get_cpu1.php.

Comment: tried running with php-cli ?

Comment: Do you think it's a proper question? You give us an error where the include path is wrong, but you never ever convince us that it isn't wrong. You haven't tell us where the Math directory is, and what is included in the .php file. I downvote the question.

Comment: @J08691, I place the php code as well.

Comment: @Royal Bg, thank you for your remark. I am learning PHP, looking for insight.

Comment: Take into account that the php interprets the paths you use for the inclusions as relative - relative to the current working directory. Which is the current working directory? Not the one where the php script is located, but from where the process is started, it is the working directory of the shell! So you have to change it! You can do that with a simple `cd` command, either by using a wrapper around the php script which first makes the `cd` and then executes the php script, or by making the `cd` at the beginning of the actual script.

Comment: @arkascha Not exactly.  It's based on the `include_path`, which, among other common script paths, usually (if not always!) includes the current working directory.

Comment: @arkascha, got it thank you - chdir(c:/php)

Comment: @landons You are right, I simplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way around this would be to `cd(__DIR__);` first thing in your script.

If you're older than PHP 5.3, use this instead: `cd(dirname(__FILE__));`